# Python - Parse Ifconfig File

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to parse an ifconfig file that will have the following format:

```
Bond10G: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 10.117.62.135  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.117.63.255
        ether 00:50:56:9e:89:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14315389  bytes 39499265855 (36.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 35686  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13009616  bytes 38702751346 (36.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Bond1G: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.117.60.135  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.117.61.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9e:ed0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:9e:ed:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1573455  bytes 172628399 (164.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10946  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 185449  bytes 50369231 (48.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        ether 00:50:56:9e:89:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13493291  bytes 39433797198 (36.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13006856  bytes 38701854528 (36.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        ether 00:50:56:9e:89:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 822097  bytes 65468597 (62.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 35673  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2760  bytes 896818 (875.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:9e:ed:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 961003  bytes 127916200 (121.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 182704  bytes 49477386 (47.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:9e:ed:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 612452  bytes 44712199 (42.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10930  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2745  bytes 891845 (870.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3164912  bytes 12725232051 (11.8 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3164912  bytes 12725232051 (11.8 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What I would like to get is a dictionary who's value is the interface, and the keys and values looking in this manner:

```
{'Bond10G' : {'mtu' : '9000', 'inet' : '10.117.62.135', 'netmask' : '255.255.254.0' # all remaining values that are space delimited}, 
'Bond1G' : {'mtu' : '9000', 'inet' : '10.117.60.135' # all remaining values that are space delimited} }
```

I have been able to split by new line to segregate each interface, however I am unsure as to how to continue. Sample code:

```
with open('ifconfig_file) as data:
    for line in data:
        temp_array = line.split("\n\n")
```

My logic would be (correct me if im wrong):

1. Split by colon to grab interface name to find the key (issue is the ether has colons in it).
2. While not empty line, take those values delimited by spaces and array[0] would be the key and array[1] would be the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage `split()` as well as regex. Here's an example where I parse `mtu` and `inet`:

```py
import re

def parse_info(interface):
  info = {}
  mtuMatches = re.findall("mtu [0-9]*\s", interface)  # find all matches for mtu
  if (len(mtuMatches) > 0):
    info['mtu'] = mtuMatches[0].replace("mtu", "").strip()  # use the first match

  inetMatches = re.findall("inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s", interface) # find all matches for inet
  if (len(inetMatches) > 0):
    info['inet'] = inetMatches[0].replace("inet", "").strip()  # use the first match
  
  # add more here
  return info

def parse_name(interface):
  parts = interface.split(":")
  return parts[0]  # grab the name

def parse_interface(interface):
  name = parse_name(interface)
  info = parse_info(interface)
  return name, info

def parse_file(data):
  interfaces = data.split("\n\n")
  parsed = {}
  for interface in interfaces:
    name, info = parse_interface(interface)
    parsed[name] = info
  return parsed

with open('ifconfig.txt') as file:
    print(parse_file(file.read()))
```

This is probably not the most performant way of doing it (if you want performance then maybe split by space and iterate over the result) but this is the cleanest in my opinion